# do we need to add optional parameter in interface c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
public interface IFoo
{
    void Bar(int i, string j="");
}

public class Test: IFoo
{
    public void Bar(int i, string j="")
    {
        
    }
}
```

Question: in interface `Ifoo` is there a need to add optional parameter `string j=""` or one should go with `string j`? What is the best practice?

Comment: Yes. You need to add optional parameters to the interface

Comment: "_What is the best practice?_" Depends whether you want to make the parameter optional or not when invoked via the interface.